# Could not get AutocompleteEntry class in a children window

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am using a AutocompleteEntry class in my code. I want to use this in a children window. Everything works fine but the list is showing in the main window when I type in the entry box in child window. The same entry is working fine with main window. Am I missing anything here ?. Here is my code..

```
from Tkinter import *

global lista
lista = ['Add', 'actions', 'additional', 'also', 'an', 'and', 'angle', 'are', 'as', 'be', 'bind', 'bracket', 'brackets', 'button', 'can', 'cases', 'configure', 'course', 'detail', 'enter', 'event', 'events', 'example', 'field', 'fields', 'for', 'give', 'important', 'in', 'information', 'is', 'it', 'just', 'key', 'keyboard', 'kind', 'leave', 'left', 'like', 'manager', 'many', 'match', 'modifier', 'most', 'of', 'or', 'others', 'out', 'part', 'simplify', 'space', 'specifier', 'specifies', 'string;', 'that', 'the', 'there', 'to', 'type', 'unless', 'use', 'used', 'user', 'various', 'ways', 'we', 'window', 'wish', 'you']
lista = [u.lower() for u in lista]
print(lista)
class AutocompleteEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, lista, *args, **kwargs):

        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.lista = lista        
        self.var = self["textvariable"]
        if self.var == '':
            self.var = self["textvariable"] = StringVar()

        self.var.trace('w', self.changed)
        self.bind("<Return>", self.selection)
        self.bind("<Up>", self.up)
        self.bind("<Down>", self.down)

        self.lb_up = False

    def changed(self, name, index, mode):  

        if self.var.get() == '':
            self.lb.destroy()
            self.lb_up = False
        else:
            words = self.comparison()

            if words:            
                if not self.lb_up:
                    self.lb = Listbox()
                    self.lb.bind("<Double-Button>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.place(x=0, y=0+self.winfo_height())
                    self.lb_up = True

                self.lb.delete(0, END)
                for w in words:
                    w = w.upper()
                    self.lb.insert(END,w)
                    print(w)    
            else:
                if self.lb_up:
                    self.lb.destroy()
                    self.lb_up = False

    def selection(self, event):

        if self.lb_up:
            self.var.set(self.lb.get(ACTIVE))
            self.lb.destroy()
            self.lb_up = False
            self.icursor(END)

    def up(self, event):

        if self.lb_up:
            if self.lb.curselection() == ():
                index = '0'
            else:
                index = self.lb.curselection()[0]
            if index != '0':                
                self.lb.selection_clear(first=index)
                index = str(int(index)-1)                
                self.lb.selection_set(first=index)
                self.lb.activate(index) 

    def down(self, event):

        if self.lb_up:
            if self.lb.curselection() == ():
                index = '0'
            else:
                index = self.lb.curselection()[0]

            if index != END:     
                self.lb.selection_clear(first=index)
                index = str(int(index)+1)        
                self.lb.selection_set(first=index)
                self.lb.activate(index) 

    def comparison(self):
        pattern = re.compile('.*' + self.var.get() + '.*')
        return [w for w in self.lista if re.match(pattern, w)]
    def reset(self):
        self.var.set("")



class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = Button(self, text="Create new window", 
                                command=self.create_window)
        self.button.pack(side="top")

    def create_window(self):
        t = Toplevel()
        e2 = AutocompleteEntry(lista, t)
        e2.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    e1 = AutocompleteEntry(lista, root)
    e1.pack()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance....!